# How can I eliminate an "@eaDir" in Zip CLI?

Tags: zip

I've tried many derivations of the following:

```
zip -r test.zip /volume1/docker/test/ -x "*.DS_Store" -x "*.pyc" -x "@eaDir"
```

The DS_Store and pic files are omitted but the directory @/eaDir and all files remain.

```
updating: volume1/docker/test/@eaDir/version.py@SynoResource
updating: volume1/docker/test/@eaDir/version.py@SynoEAStream
updating: volume1/docker/test/@eaDir/start.py@SynoResource
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Try escaping the @? `\@eaDir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Patterns are paths with optional wildcards and match paths as stored in archive.

So you would need to use:

```
zip -r test.zip /volume1/docker/test/ -x '*/@eaDir/*' -x '*.DS_Store' -x '*.pyc'
```

The single quotes pass the `*` wildcard on to zip, who matches the path against the one you gave it for the archive. (Your double-quotes would work, too, but I would prefer single-qutoes here to avoid any misinterpretation of variable names or command substitutions, etc).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the explanation. I ended up with -x '*/@eaDir/*' which skipped them in all directories.

Comment: Happy it helped, Stephen! I updated my answer to use `*/@eaDir/*` like your Question intended. If you feel like this solves the problem, please click the checkmark next to it; thank you, and welcome to the U&L site!